# How do I use use pylint within a virtualenv while using system neovim? (neovim + ale + pylint)

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pylint, neovim

I'm hoping to use `ale` + `pylint` within a virtual environment without having to install `pylint` into every virtualenv I'm working in at the time.  When I use `import <something>` that's only installed within the virtualenv it can't find it because `ale` (or `pylint`) is not using the virtual environment that neovim's `:CheckHealth` reports.  For example while editing a new python script within a virtualenv where `gunicorn` is installed I see `import-error: Unable to import 'gunicorn'`.

I've tried setting `g:ale_python_auto_virtualenv` to `1` but this has no effect.
I've tried setting `g:ale_virtualenv_dir_names` to `'[]'` but this has no effect.

`g:python3_host_prog` is set to `"/opt/homebrew/bin/python3"`
`pylint` is installed in the system environment
`neovim` is installed in the system environment

The problem I'm having seems similar to https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/issues/1777 but my issue is much simpler than that.  I just want to not have to install pylint inside every virtualenv I'm coding within.

Perhaps there's an argument for pylint I'm missing that will tell it to use the virtualenv I'm working in?  I read the massive number of lines from `pylint --help` and didn't see anything applicable in there.

*Before entering virtual environment:*

```
➜ pip freeze | egrep '(neovim|pylint|gunicorn)'
neovim==0.3.1
pylint==2.16.2
```

*After entering virtual environment (neither of the above are installed - this is on purpose):*

```
(.venv) ➜ pip freeze | egrep '(neovim|pylint|gunicorn)'
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

**neovim config**:

```
let g:python3_host_prog = '/opt/homebrew/bin/python3'

" Show linting only in the status bar
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0

let g:ale_linters = {
\   '*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'],
\   'python': ['pylint'],
\}

" Ale Fixing
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
let g:ale_fixers = {
\   'python': ['black'],
\}
```

**ALEInfo:**

```
 Current Filetype: python
Available Linters: ['bandit', 'cspell', 'flake8', 'flakehell', 'jedils', 'mypy', 'prospector', 'pycln', 'pycodestyle', 'pydocstyle', 'pyflakes', 'pylama', 'pylint', 'pylsp', 'pyre'
, 'pyright', 'refurb', 'ruff', 'unimport', 'vulture']
  Enabled Linters: ['pylint']
  Ignored Linters: []
 Suggested Fixers:
  'add_blank_lines_for_python_control_statements' - Add blank lines before control statements.
  'autoflake' - Fix flake issues with autoflake.
  'autoimport' - Fix import issues with autoimport.
  'autopep8' - Fix PEP8 issues with autopep8.
  'black' - Fix PEP8 issues with black.
  'isort' - Sort Python imports with isort.
  'pycln' - remove unused python import statements
  'pyflyby' - Tidy Python imports with pyflyby.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'reorder-python-imports' - Sort Python imports with reorder-python-imports.
  'ruff' - A python linter/fixer for Python written in Rust
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'yapf' - Fix Python files with yapf.
 Linter Variables:
let g:ale_python_auto_pipenv = 0
let g:ale_python_auto_poetry = 0
let g:ale_python_auto_virtualenv = 0
let g:ale_python_pylint_auto_pipenv = 0
let g:ale_python_pylint_auto_poetry = 0
let g:ale_python_pylint_change_directory = 1
let g:ale_python_pylint_executable = 'pylint'
let g:ale_python_pylint_options = ''
let g:ale_python_pylint_use_global = 0
let g:ale_python_pylint_use_msg_id = 0
 Global Variables:
let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_disable_lsp = 0
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
let g:ale_fixers = {'python': ['black']}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {'*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'], 'python': ['pylint']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_linters_ignore = {}
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_root = {}
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_neovim_diagnostics_api = 0
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:
(finished - exit code 0) ['/bin/zsh', '-c', '''pylint'' --version']
<<<OUTPUT STARTS>>>
pylint 2.16.2
astroid 2.14.2
Python 3.11.2 (main, Feb 13 2023, 03:31:04) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
<<<OUTPUT ENDS>>>
(executable check - success) pylint
(finished - exit code 22) ['/bin/zsh', '-c', 'cd ''/Users/lstewart/Projects/LSWAC'' && ''pylint'' --output-format text --msg-template="{path}:{line}:{column}: {msg_id} ({symbol}) {
msg}" --reports n --from-stdin ''/Users/lstewart/Projects/LSWAC/temp.py'' < ''/var/folders/mj/b2t_3cyx5gg9l_tnykyjtqt80000gn/T/nvim.lstewart/7SPaeQ/1/temp.py''']
<<<OUTPUT STARTS>>>
************* Module temp
temp.py:1:0: C0114 (missing-module-docstring) Missing module docstring
temp.py:1:0: E0401 (import-error) Unable to import 'gunicorn'
temp.py:1:0: W0611 (unused-import) Unused import gunicorn
------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00)
```

**CheckHealth:**

```
...
## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/opt/homebrew/bin/python3"
  - INFO: Executable: /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
  - INFO: Python version: 3.11.2
  - INFO: pynvim version: 0.4.3
  - OK: Latest pynvim is installed.

## Python virtualenv
  - INFO: $VIRTUAL_ENV is set to: /Users/lstewart/Projects/LSWAC/.venv
  - INFO: Python version: 3.11.2
  - OK: $VIRTUAL_ENV provides :!python.
...
```